# Different compositions of matrices

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have 3 Images and A, B and C are matrices represent the intensity distribution of each image. W is a composition of these images with different percentages, for example:

```
W = x*A + y*B + z*C
```

where x, y and z are percentage of selection from each image.

For example:

```
W1 = 0.25*A + 0.36*B + 0.7*C
W2 = 0.25*B + 0.36*C + 0.7*A

             .
             .
             .
Wn = x*A + y*B + z*C
```

here for example, I select 25% of A

How can I calculate the coefficients x, y and z, to generate different combinations of A, B and C?

One possible solution is use Binomial or Taylor series  or any other series, to calculate these coefficients, then use permutation to exchange the positions of these coefficients in **W** equation in order to generate different **W** each time. But I am not sure how to do this, because I am not a specialist in Math or statistics.

Comment: Are you trying to select x, y, and z to best match W?

Comment: @eyeballfrog No, the match is not necessary, I just want to generate different **W** from different combination of A, B and C by changing x, y and z. I have edited the question, please check the example.